# Native Android app activity flow for specific data model

Tags: android, android-fragments

We are developing native Android application with SAP ERP as backend.

Most answers we can get from SAP Community Network but this one is Android specific:

Our data model consists of two level header items tables `(header, items, and two more items in the first level items)`.

**My idea is to use this activity flow:**

Login activity, Search activity (for selecting work orders),

List view activity (for displaying selected work orders),

Master detail activity (with items on the left and details on the right fragment).

Work order header have no importance because it will be created in SAP, not in the field, so information from List view would be sufficient.

What is important is items (first and second level) because there are the fields which is to be filled on field (and offline). My concern is how to display those two second level items. Through Table layouts in Detail fragment of Master detail flow? Or maybe to open new activity (but then again will have to use List and details). Can you give me some advice about this?